# Firebase/Firestore: Value of type 'DocumentReference' has no member 'get'

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to access a document and get value from the fields so I can login as a user and retrieve that user data. I have the following code that will not compile because I keep getting the error 'Value of type 'DocumentReference' has no member 'get'. Please help!

[image]

Comment: Please provide your code as text. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What programming language are you using? Also note that it more likely that someone will help if you provide the code as text, instead of as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `newDoc` is a `DocumentReference` object, which is nothing more than a reference to a (potential) document in the database.

To [load the document from the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) you need to call `getdocument()` on the reference, as shown in this snippet from the documentation:

```
let docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF")

docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
    if let document = document, document.exists {
        let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
        print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")
    } else {
        print("Document does not exist")
    }
}
```

The data is only available within the completion handler, as shown above. Trying to access it outside of there will lead to timing problems, as the data is loaded asynchronously.

Comment: Thank you! Thats exactly what I was missing.